# How do I get a queued brew to start?

Tags: fiz

I have a brew in the queue but I wouldn't start it just sits there and it has all ingredients needed... So how do I start it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the last beer you brewed out of the Holding Area. Either move it to storage, or send all of the bottles out to market to be sold.

You can see this by going to the menu, selecting **Manage** and then **Storage.**

Your team won't start brewing until the holding area is empty.